# Algebraic operation corresponding to "taking residues at roots of unity"

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, cv.complex-variables, ra.rings-and-algebras

I'm not sure if this is more appropriate for MO or MSE, this is a question that came up in actual research, but it's of a somewhat elementary nature.

Let $R$ be the ring of rational functions with poles at roots of unity, is there a sufficiently nice way to algebraically describe the operation on $R$ of "taking the sum of residues at roots of unity of $f(x)dx/x$? This operation takes $\frac{x^a}{x^m-1}$ to $1$ if $a$ is a multiple of $m$ and 0 otherwise, and this determines it on the entirety of $R$. By "sufficiently nice", I mean I'd like to be able to describe it purely algebraically, and hopefully without making reference to complex numbers.

What I envisioned was something like "taking the algebraic residue at $x^m-1$", where $m$ is the lcm of the orders of the roots of unity in the denominator of $f$. However this operation is not well defined, as to express an arbitrary polynomial as a series in $x^m-1$ I need to to take $m$th roots. For example, consider the case of $x/x^m-1$, after renaming $x^m-1$ to $\alpha$, the result becomes $Res_{\alpha}\frac{(\alpha+1)^{1/m}}{\alpha}\frac{d\alpha}{\alpha+1}$.

I still get the correct answer if I take the appropriate residues at each branch and sum them (resulting in 0), but this still requires complex analysis. I could alternatively just declare such functions have 0 residue, but I don't have any justification for doing that.

EDIT: Because of the particulars of my situation, I'm specifically looking for an interpretation somehow in terms of the functions $x^\alpha-1$.

Answer (score 6):

The sum of the (finite) residues of a rational function $F(x)$ is equal to 
 $$ -\mathrm{Res}(F(x),x=\infty) = \mathrm{Res}\left( \frac{1}{x^2}F(1/x), x=0\right). $$
This is just the coefficient of $x$ in the Laurent expansion with finitely many negative exponents of $F(1/x)$ at $x=0$.

Comment: I was actually aware of this fact. I realize now that my phrasing of this question was probably not great, apologies for not being specific enough.  Because of the particulars of my situation, I'm specifically looking for an interpretation somehow in terms of the functions $x^\alpha-1$.

Comment: @ANonnyMouse: I am not sure what you mean by "in terms of the functions $x^\alpha-1$." For $f(x)$ with poles at roots of unity, the sum of the residues of $x^\alpha f(x)$ for $\alpha$ sufficiently large has the form $\sum_{j=0}^n c_j(\alpha)\alpha^j$, where $c_j(\alpha)$ is a periodic function of $\alpha$.